# Issue to display data from a module into another

Tags: module, mongoose, crud, mean-stack

I'm a beginner to MEAN.js and have an issue with displaying some datas from one module into another.

I've successfully created a new CRUD module "Jobs" which contains a list of jobs for my company.
I would like to associate a job from this list to a user (which is another crud module contained in the sample code)
When i'm editing a user on the admin panel i would like to be able to choose a job from a list and set it to the user in the database.

Here is what i've from now on :

user.server.model.js

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  //username, firstname etc.
  job: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'job'
  }
});
```

job.server.model.js

```
var JobSchema = new Schema({
   name:{
      type: String
   }
});
```

My html where i try to link them both :

edit-user.client.view.html

```
//Set a job for a user
<select ng-options="job.name for job in vm.jobs"></select> // <--- this doesn't work
```

Thank you for your help :) !

edit : 
user.client.controller.js

```
angular.module('users.admin').controller('UserController', ['$scope', '$state', 'Authentication', 'userResolve',function ($scope, $state, Authentication, userResolve) {
$scope.authentication = Authentication;
$scope.user = userResolve; //...
```

job.client.controller.js

```
angular
    .module('jobs')
    .controller('JobsController', JobsController);

  JobsController.$inject = ['$scope', '$state', 'Authentication', 'jobResolve'];

  function RolesController ($scope, $state, Authentication, job) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.authentication = Authentication;
    vm.job = job; //...
```

list-job.client.controller.js

```
angular
  .module('jobs')
  .controller('JobsListController', JobsListController);
JobsListController.$inject = ['JobsService'];
function JobsListController(JobsService) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.roles = JobsService.query();
}
```

Resolved, injecting my jobs service into my user controller did it:

```
angular.module('users.admin').controller('UserController', ['$scope', '$state', 'Authentication', 'JobsService', 'userResolve',
  function ($scope, $state, Authentication, JobsService, userResolve) {
    $scope.authentication = Authentication;
    $scope.user = userResolve;
    $scope.jobs = JobsService.query();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This have to be done in your server side endpoint.
Suppose you have a route like that:

```
router.post('/users/', function(req, res, next) {
    var user = new User(req.body);
    user.job = req.job;

    user.save(function(err, user) {
         if(err) { return next(err); }        
         res.json(user);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, I understand that this is needed to update the user with the job selected, but I didn't explain clearly my problem, it is upstream of it (i'm a real newbie with mean.js). Actually, the vm.jobs isn't retrieving anything from my database and i don't know how to call it from inside of the edit user's view as it is in another module.

Comment: Can you post your AngularJS controller code? Where you are loading Jobs and Users from your API. I suppose you need to have both loaded in the $scope of your controller used in the view.

Comment: I have one controller for each module : one for user and one for role, i think it might be the problem, I never have both loaded in the $scope.